# How to override correctly the row' style of PrimeNg Table?

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I have PrimeNg Table editable by columns and I would like to manage the style of my rows to fit with a specific line height, an overflow hidden and a background color hidden as well when the row is editable or not.

My actual template is here :

```
<p-table #dt class="menus-table" [value]="detail.items">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
      <tr class="menu-tr-header">
        <th style="width: 20%">Label</th>
        <th style="width: 70%">URL</th>
        <th style="width: 10%">Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-ri="rowIndex">
      <tr class="menu-tr-content">
        <td pEditableColumn>
          <p-cellEditor class="menu-cell-editable">
            <ng-template pTemplate="input" >
                <input pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="rowData.label"
                       [disabled]="mode == 'normal'">
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                {{rowData.label}}
            </ng-template>
          </p-cellEditor>
        </td>
        <td pEditableColumn>
          <p-cellEditor class="menu-cell-editable">
            <ng-template pTemplate="input">
              <input pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="rowData.url"
                     [disabled]="mode == 'normal'"
                     placeholder="#/list/... " >
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template pTemplate="output">
              {{rowData.url}}
            </ng-template>
          </p-cellEditor>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>
  </p-table>
```

And here is my css :

```
.menus-table-header {
    margin: 15px 0;

    nav {
        background-color: #f4f4f4;
        border-color: #f4f4f4;
    }   
}

.menus-table {
    th, td {
        background-color: transparent;
        border: none;
    }

    .menu-tr-header {
        border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
    }

    .menu-tr-content {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
        background-color: transparent;
    }

    .menu-cell-editable {
        background-color: transparent !important;
        font-weight: bold;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
        line-height: 1.42857143;
    }
}
```

I don't really understand why menu-cell-editable isn't applyed and why I have a strange behavior when I pass from edit mode to normal mode and vice-versa as you can see below:

[image: Off edit mode]

[image: On edit mode]

Comment: Primefaces own style is sometimes hard to override, try to inspect your component and see if your style is there (else you have to check that), and if it's overrided, then you could add to yours !important syntax, or change it to make it more specific

Comment: If you use a thrid-party Angular component and try to override the styles, usually you should override with ::ng-deep {  } because their component don't set encapsulation to None.

Comment: In fact, I'm reallizing that it's not only an issue with the scope of the selector but with the css itself ! I added a rule ```white-space: nowrap;``` and it started to change in a better way but the overflow rule doesn't have any effet...